# Is it possible to send keys to inactive window via any c/c++ library?

Tags: unity, c++, c

I'm developing a program where I need to control an inactive window by sending a couple of keys. I was wondering if there is any c/c++ library to do so on Ubuntu (and linux in general) ? I googled a lot but there seem to be a lots of examples and libraries for windows but non for linux environment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dig into it a little bit and found about that I can use either "xdotool" command line tool or libxdo (for c++ intergration) for it.